# Duda sobre un diagrama uml

Tags: java, uml

Tengo una duda con un diagrama uml que me dejaron, apenas estoy aprendiendo java y acabo de ver colecciones y relaciones muchos a muchos. Me presentaron el siguiente diagrama uml.

[image: Diagrama uml asociado]

En el metodo agregarLibro(lib Libro, aut Autor) de la clase Controller libro, se especifica que un para que un libro a la lista, el autor que se recibe como parametro debe existir en la lista de "autores.

Ahora bien, tengo entendido que, ya que la lista "autores" le pertenece a la clase ControllerAutor, y esta no tiene relacion con ControllerLibro no puedo hacer esto:

```java
import control.ControllerAutor;
public class ControllerLibro {

    ControllerAutor controladorAutor = new ControllerAutor;

}
```

Mi pregunta es si hay alguna manera de acceder a la lista "autores" sin crear un objeto de tipo ControllerAutor.

De antemano me disculpo si mi pregunta no es clara y si es causa de alguna molestia, jamas he usado este sitio y realmente me daba un poco de pena preguntar.

Muchisimas gracias por su atencion.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como haber, hay muchas. Nada te impideria preguntar a la db si existe ese autor. Nada impediria que levantaras el objeto y tambien le preguntaras. Seria raro recibir el id de un autor y que no exista. Creo que hace falta mas info para darte una respuesta contundente. Y esto, no tiene nada que ver con java per se.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente hay forma, pero requiere algunas modificaciones sería mediante el acceso por el controlador de libros, y deberías de agregarle un método para que te permita obtener los libros; Ya se maediante un `obtenTodosLosLibros():Libro` o mediante un `buscaLibros(libros:Libros[])` y por lo mismo la forma de consulta para obtener los distintos autores sería:

```
List<Autor> autores = ControllerLibro.obtenTodosLosLibros().stream().map(libro->autor).distinct().collect(Collectors.asList());
```

o mediante

```
List<Autor> autores = ControllerLibro.buscaLibros(arregloDeLibros).stream().map(libro->autor).distinct().collect(Collectors.asList());
```

como verás uso el stream api por simplicidad, ya que nos permite mapear de un tipo a otro usando un lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiero no agregar relaciones entre controladores y en su lugar mover las listas a las clases de entidad que estas poseen (la lista de autores a la clase Autor y la lista de libros a la clase Libro) mediante un atributo estatico y acceder a estas mediante un metodo (estatico tambien), getTodos() por ejemplo. De esta manera los controladores manejan solo dependencias a las entidades, ya no asociaciones, y si tu ControladorLibro requiere le lista de autores entonces agrega una dependencia a la clase Autor.

En este momento no puedo subir un diagrama, pero si no he sido lo suficientemente claro puedo editar mi repuesta y agregar una mas tarde si así lo desea